# QtPropertyBrowser compiler error when adding moc_objectcontroller.cpp to Visual Studio source tree

Tags: visual-studio, qt, properties

I'm using the QtPropertyBrowser in my project, based on the `ObjectController` example. I use Visual Studio 2010 as IDE and version 5.2.1 of Qt (I could reproduce the error for Qt 4.7 and 4.8).

All `moc_*.cpp` files are added to the source tree `GeneratedFiles\$(Configuration)`. Unfortunately, this results in the following compiler error:

```
    2>  moc_objectcontroller.cpp
    2>  GeneratedFiles\Release\moc_objectcontroller.cpp(70): error C2027: use of undefined type 'ObjectControllerPrivate'
    2>  c:\***\guimain\generatedfiles\release\../../src/objectcontroller.h(45) : see declaration of 'ObjectControllerPrivate'
    2>  GeneratedFiles\Release\moc_objectcontroller.cpp(70): error C2227: left of '->slotValueChanged' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
```

When I remove `moc_objectcontroller.cpp` from the source tree (without actually deleting the file on disk), the project builds and runs fine. All other `moc_*.cpp` files *have* to be in the source tree, otherwise the project would not link.

Does someone know, why the compiler produces an error? Is there a solution / work-around you know of?

**Edit: on request the corresponding code files:**

- http://pastebin.com/2JQaa3Dr (moc_objectcontroller.cpp)
- http://pastebin.com/5iBQX59u (objectcontroller.cpp)
- http://pastebin.com/M2mm66R9 (objectcontroller.h)

Comment: Works fine in my MSVC2012 and Qt 5.1.0. Please show content of `moc_objectcontroller.cpp` file and provide a link to the exact version of example you used. Also maybe something is wrong with your Qt installation, try to reinstall.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov: thanks for your comment. The exact code can be found in the added links. I have tried multiple versions of Qt, both built from source and installed. Also in MSVC2012 (in VC2010 mode) I get the same compiler error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could probably be your

```
 ObjectControllerPrivate *d_ptr;
```

conflicting with

```
 QScopedPointer<QObjectData> d_ptr;
```

inherited from QWidget/QObject **d_ptr** member variable.

Rename it and try again.

Comment: That seems to work. I will test in the next two hours on another system, running another Qt version and MSVC2010. On success I will award the answer, of course. Thanks!